# Is “This room was slept in by Milton” grammatical even though ‘sleep’ is an intransitive verb?

Tags: passive-voice

> Milton slept in this room.

According to   [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sleep), *sleep* is an intransitive verb (A1). So we shouldn't be able to rewrite the sentence in the English  passive voice.

But I want the most important part of the sentence to be *the room* and not *Milton*, so I wrote

> This room was slept in by Milton.

First, is this grammatical?

Second, I thought the passive voice in English can only use transitive verbs??

I researched about the English Passive Voice on [Education First](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/) and Purdue University's  [Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/539/).

This answer has been marked as a possible duplicate of [Intransitive verbs with preposition in passive sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193000/intransitive-verbs-with-preposition-in-passive-sentences). But the most upvoted answer there does not address the property of *intransitive* as assigned by the dictionary, which is an integral part of this question. In addition the same answer there is confusing  because it says both that transitivity is not a property of verbs and yet ends up talking about transitive verbs. In addition, the same answer does not explicitly deal with verbs other than "sense verbs". So I'm not sure if that answer applies to *to sleep*.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical and perfectly fine.

Comment: You are saved by the preposition "in." Had you said "The bed was slept by Goldilocks," that would have been wrong for the reason you have given when you posed the question.

Comment: There are dangers in saying 'V is an intransitive verb'. Would you say _sleep_ is being used intransitively in 'This tent will sleep six large adults'?

Comment: Because of the excellent answer provided by tchrist below, ***please do not close this question,*** even if it addressed elsewhere as a possible "duplicate."

Comment: @Mark Hubbard Why can't tchrist's answer be preserved in a combined thread?

Comment: This is the room Milton slept in.

Comment: Erm, if you want the most important part of the sentence to be *the room* then it needs to go at the END of the sentence. That's where we put the important and new information. The most natural reason to use the passive there is if the room has already been mentioned (I see it has because it uses a definite article), and is therefore old and boring, and if Milton has not been mentioned yet and is therefore interesting and new. That would be a good reason to use the passive version.

Comment: I'd avoid using EF International Language School's website as a source, btw ...

Comment: Hi Clare, do you still want this question reopened? If so, I'll start proceedings.

Comment: I'd use:  *This is the room in which Milton slept.*

Comment: @Araucaria I've [posted in meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10872/can-we-please-reopen-this-question). I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @Clare It worked! (Best and quickest way to do it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**ᴛʟᴅʀ:** Yes, this construction is perfectly grammatical* in English, and perfectly common as well. There are subtle restrictions on it, however, so not all such transforms produce things that sound right, or at least good, to a native speaker.

<sub>**ɴᴏᴛᴇ** 1: It requires *preposition stranding*, which some decry — but they’re wrong. <sup>:)</sup>
**ɴᴏᴛᴇ** 2: [Like Pullum](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922), I won’t be using the confusing term *“voice”* here, though, because [this is not about Latin.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/)<sup>:)</sup></sub>

---

## Prepositional Passives

This construction is called the [***prepositional passive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Prepositional_passive) construction. It is one of several constructions sometimes dubiously referred to as a “pseudo-passive” one.

Passives occur when a sentence (well, a clause) with an object is rearranged so that what had previously been an object is now that sentence’s grammatical subject governing its verb, and the old subject, if included, ends up being the object of a prepositional phrase starting with *by*.  Another way to say this is that passives are clauses whose subjects and objects get swapped around, even though the [agent and patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)) remain the same.

This **reversal of subject and object** is most commonly seen in clauses with direct objects, but it can also happen in clauses with indirect objects or even prepositional objects as well. Watch how in these pairs, the subject and object shown in the first of each pair exchange positions in the second, making it a passive:

#### Passive with Direct object

- The dog bit the boy.
- The boy **was bitten *by*** the dog.

#### Passive with Indirect object

- The school sent the winners prizes.
- The winners **were sent *prizes by*** the school.

#### Passive with Prepositional object

- A thousand passing schoolboys have peed off of this bridge.
- This bridge **has been peed *off of by*** a thousand passing schoolboys.

Just because the verb *to pee* is intransitive does not forbid it from being used in passives. It just can’t be a passive formed by rearranging a ***direct* object** into a subject, since there can be no direct object with an intransitive verb.

But intransitive verbs can certainly take prepositions, and these ***prepositional* objects** can be used to create passives, and indeed often are.

You’ll see in the examples I’ve provided that the passive formed by the direct object has nothing between the *be* + participle and the word *by* that precedes the original subject. But with passives formed by the indirect object or the prepositional object, there are extra bits after the particple.  I’ve marked this by setting in italic the part after the participle up through the word *by* in my examples above.

## Passives, per Pullum

In his most excellent essay on [“The Passive in English”, Geoffrey Pullum writes](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922) that:

> In English the prepositional passive is quite frequent, especially in relatively informal style. Most languages don't have anything like it (Norwegian is a rare example of a language that does).

Why does Pullum mention informal styles? Because prepositional passives require something we call [***preposition stranding***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding), which is when the object of a preposition has been moved to some other position in a sentence than immediately following that preposition. Since with prepositional passives we're promoting that object to the sentence subject, this by necessity strands that preposition.

Of course, preposition stranding is perfectly normal in English, and always has been. But this is one of those constructions “up with which” certain pseudo-Latinate Victorian registers would so notoriously not put.  That’s why it is sometimes considered less formal: because it’s something that informal registers are more likely to put up with outside of Victoria’s earshot.

Pullum goes on to observe that English prepositional passives do have restrictions about which ones are valid and which aren’t:

> There are some peculiar restrictions on prepositional passives in English. One is that there can be a difference in acceptability according to whether the subject denotes an entity that is tangibly altered in state: *This bottom bunk has been slept in* is dramatically more acceptable than ??*The bottom bunk has been slept above*, apparently because sleeping in a bunk bed alters its state (the sheets are wrinkled and so on), while sleeping in the top bunk above it doesn't alter its state at all. Intuitively, you use a prepositional passive when the VP expresses a relevantly important property of the subject. That's a restriction on prepositional passives, because there is nothing peculiar about the active version *Someone has slept above this bottom bunk*. (Why would a language have a restriction like that? Who knows. I don't make or try to enforce any of the rules; I am merely trying to explain what the rules seem to be.)

A native speaker “knows” which prepositional passives are allowed and which ones are not, but non-natives attempting to learn the language by inferred rules should probably take some care with them.

#### Footnotes

This is the footnote for the asterisk in the opening summary:

- Remember that “grammatical” just means that something sounds “right” to a native speaker, and that “not grammatical” just means that something sounds “not right” to a native speaker.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Well done, tchrist.

Comment: +1 Note, however the striking difference in *X has been **pissed off** by a thousand passing schoolboys*, where *X* is probably a senior English master.

Comment: (+1) Yet: 1. Is my sentence grammatical. It's important to me to explicitly answer that question. 2. Your answer does not use the term  *passive voice* in it. Could you edit your answer to address this?

Comment: @Clare I thought its grammaticality was implicit in my describing the construction and including multiple references. I have documented that this construction is not merely used by native speakers but that it is indeed common, which by definition makes it grammatical. I spoke of passives throughout; what more is it you wish me to say? The term *voice* is meaningless in English, but if you would like to ask that question on [latin.se] it will probably garner an answer better suited to it.

Comment: @Clare I didn't use *voice* because as Pullum writes, “This essay avoids using the term **voice**. That's the rather strange traditional name for the distinction between active and passive. It mainly confuses people: The active/passive "voice" contrast has nothing to do with finding your voice, or having a loud voice, or the authentic voice of the oppressed.”

Comment: Pullum’s statement that Norwegian is a “rare” example of another language that has prepositional passives seems in need of a “[citation needed]” tag to me. Unless you specifically require preposition stranding to be an intrinsic part of what constitutes prepositional passive (it isn’t), at the very least all Germanic languages have prepositional passives. Even with that requirement, all the North Germanic languages have it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was wondering about that one myself.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't entirely understand your comment above. Could you illustrate with an example? (of a prepositional passive without preposition standing) The thought does come to mind that if only North Germanic languages have it then - even though we live in a North Germanic language area - the total number of languages with P-stranding still might be very small indeed. (Imagine if we were talking about a feature which only occurred in a handful of languages somewhere more obscure, for example) There are passives with preposition phrases as Subjects in English ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... But they wouldn't be the same type of construction at all, because the Subject would not be the object of a PP in the related active construction, it would be the DO. "After Christmas was thought to be the best time to have the party", for example.

Comment: @Araucaria There are languages (such as the Celtic languages, and others beside them, I'm sure) where separating the preposition from its object in a passive construction is entirely possible without the preposition being stranded—a repeated, pleonastic pronoun is just added instead, so you'd end up with something like “The room was slept in it”. There are also languages where the preposition would instead attach to the verb in a passive construction so you'd have something like “The room was in-slept”. In both cases, the preposition is removed from its main object, but not _stranded_ as such.

Comment: @Araucaria And of course there are languages where a prepositional phrase can remain intact as the subject in the passive, i.e., “In the room was slept by Milton”. And I'm sure there are other ingenious ways languages have come up with of passivising prepositional constructions that don't necessarily involve stranding.

Comment: [Malagasy has about half a dozen varieties of passive](http://people.linguistics.mcgill.ca/~lisa.travis/papers/PassivesStatesRoots.pdf), each used for fronting different types of NP into subject position. Indonesian languages like this don't do "passive" in the same way as I-E languages do. Indeed, there's lots of controversy about the universality of "passive". See [this article](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/acehnesequestions.pdf) for an example.

Comment: 'Remember that “grammatical” just means that something sounds “right” to a native speaker, and that “not grammatical” just means that something sounds “not right” to a native speaker.' _But which native speaker? Geoff, Noam, or Arfur Daley?_